# Enforcing relationships between types safely

Tags: java, oop, generics, type-safety

I am building a system for writing code about people who take pictures of birds (the real system isn't actually about that, I use birds here to replace the business logic that I can't post). I'm having trouble keeping my code type safe while also enforcing all of the relationships I want and avoiding the code becoming super messy. Here's what I have.

There are three types of birds

```
public interface BirdType {}
public class BlueJay implements BirdType {}
public class Cardinal implements BirdType {}
public class Canary implements BirdType {}
```

For each type of bird, there's a type of camera specialized in taking pictures of that bird, and a special bird call which attracts birds of that type.

```
public interface BirdCamera<BT extends BirdType> {}
public interface BirdCall<BT extends BirdType> {}
public class BlueJayCamera implements BirdCamera<BlueJay> {}
public class CardinalCamera implements BirdCamera<Cardinal> {}
public class CanaryCamera implements BirdCamera<Canary> {}
public class BlueJayCall implements BirdCall<BlueJay> {}
public class CardinalCall implements BirdCall<Cardinal> {}
public class CanaryCall implements BirdCall<Canary> {}
```

These parts are combined in the Photographer interface, which enforces a relationship between the parts of a photographer for its implementers.

```
public interface Photographer 
  <BT extends BirdType,
   CAM extends BirdCamera<BT>,
   CAL extends BirdCall<BT>> 
{
  CAM getPhotographersCamera();
  CAL getPhotographersBirdCall();
  void examineCamera(CAM camera);
}
```

and it is implemented by three classes like this, one for each bird:

```
public class BlueJayPhotographer implements Photographer<BlueJay, BlueJayCamera, BlueJayCall> {

  @Override
  public BlueJayCamera getPhotographersCamera() {
    //Do bluejay specific logic
    return new BlueJayCamera();
  }

  @Override
  public BlueJayCall getPhotographersBirdCall() {
    //Do bluejay specific logic
    return new BlueJayCall();
  }

  @Override
  public void examineCamera(BlueJayCamera camera) {
    //Do bluejay specific logic
  }
}
```

One desirable thing about this is that it prevents future mistakes by other developers. Someone else can't later create

```
public class ConfusedPhotographer implements Photographer<BlueJay, CardinalCamera, CanaryCall>
```

because the constraints in Photographer prevent it.

When a class wants to use a photographer, they invoke the PhotographerProvider

```
public class PhotographerProvider {
  public Photographer get(int birdCode) {
    if (birdCode == 0) {
      return new BlueJayPhotographer();
    }
    else if (birdCode == 1) {
      return new CardinalPhotographer();
    }
    else if (birdCode == 2) {
      return new CanaryPhotographer();
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported bird code: " + birdCode);
    }
  }
}
```

One such class that needs to use photographers in many of its methods is the NationalPark, one of the core classes of my application. Here's an example NationalPark method:

```
  public void importantMethod(PhotographerProvider photographerProvider) {
    // blah blah logic goes here
    int mostCommonBirdType = 1;
    Photographer typicalTourist = photographerProvider.get(mostCommonBirdType);
    BirdCamera cam = typicalTourist.getPhotographersCamera();
    typicalTourist.examineCamera(cam);
    // blah blah more logic here
  }
```

The compiler doesn't like the last line of that method, and produces a warning:
Unchecked call to 'examineCamera(CAM)' as a member of raw type 'birdexample.Photographer'

I don't want this warning, but I can't find a way to fix it that doesn't cause an error someplace else... I'd also like to avoid making a gigantic mess where every class in my entire program has to be paramaterized with a bird type, camera, and call. How can I do this (short of just suppressing/ignoring the warning)?

Comment: Why do you think cameras and photographers should be of different types for different birds? Why can't a photographer of blue jays decide he has enough photos of those, and start taking pictures of canaries instead?

Comment: The cameras, photographers, and birds are all replacements for pieces of business logic which do need to be of different types, because they do different things. I apologize if my metaphor is imperfect.

Comment: But does the fact they do different things need to be part of the type? As in, birds all call, cameras take pictures, photographers all have cameras and favourite birds... But you can do all of that without generics. What are you doing with generics that can't be done with regular polymorphism?

Comment: The benefit I'm trying to gain here is that a future developer can't create the "ConfusedPhotographer" that I described in the question. If there's a way I can do all this without generics, I'll be _thrilled_.

Comment: Well, how do you call the `examineCamera` method? Do you only ever call it with your own camera? If so, why get the camera, only to pass it back in - just make it `examineCamera()`. There's one type variable gone.

Comment: More generally, have you heard of the [Hollywood Principle](http://wiki.c2.com/?HollywoodPrinciple) ("don't call us, we'll call you"). That can be a good way of keeping the relationships between types of internal variables hidden.

Comment: Not by that name, but yeah, I'm familiar with that idea. In the real code there is no examineCamera method, I just added that because I needed a method that would have the warning without making this question as complex as the real system. However, I do think you've helped me see that I'm not necessarily getting as much from the generics as I am losing in complexity. I'll look into seeing if we can just get rid of them. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specific example can be done without warnings as follows:

```
Photographer<?, ?, ?> typicalTourist = photographerProvider.get(mostCommonBirdType);
foo(typicalTourist);

<BT extends BirdType,
 CAM extends BirdCamera<BT>> void foo(Photographer<BT, CAM, ?> typicalTourist) {
    CAM cam = typicalTourist.getPhotographersCamera();
    typicalTourist.examineCamera(cam);
}
```

But I would caution about your design. Honestly, anything more than 1 type variable is pretty unwieldy. 2 is tolerable for cases like maps, but 3 is just getting a bit crazy - you end up filling half your line with the type declaration. *6* (the number you say you have in the real code) is thoroughly into the territory of hating yourself, hating your colleagues, or both.

Think carefully if you really need these generics - you might save a lot of eye strain if you can get rid of them.

Comment: I agree with you. I actually inherited ownership of this system from another engineer, and in the real system, there are 6 type variables, not just 3. Every class where these generics are used has the entire class parameterized, and many of them have these warnings anyway. I was struggling to see if there was a way I could improve the readability of the surrounding classes (such as by not having these params) while keeping my type enforcement. But perhaps I should check how important that enforcement really is vs readability.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48509029/7294647), your `PhotographerProvider#get` method issues a compiler warning due to its raw return type `Photographer`.  To fix that, you can use the following:

```
public class PhotographerProvider {
    public Photographer<?, ?, ?> get(int birdCode) {
        if (birdCode == 0) {
            return new BlueJayPhotographer();
        } else if (birdCode == 1) {
            return new CardinalPhotographer();
        } else if (birdCode == 2) {
            return new CanaryPhotographer();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported bird code: " + birdCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method PhotographerProvider.get return a raw Photographer of unknow type of camera and birds:

```
public Photographer get(int birdCode) {
[...]
}
```

you could instead write something like

```
public   <BT extends BirdType, CAM extends BirdCamera<BT>, CAL extends BirdCall<BT>> Photographer<BT, CAM, CALL> get(int birdCode) {
[...]
}
```

So you get type safety. The problem is that at least with recent version of java you could choose any BT type when calling the get method and it would be same for the compiler.

In fact all this system doesn't bring you much type safety. For example you instanciate the right type actually with an integer. And when one use a photographer he has no idea of the bird type or camera so he doen't really benefit of all of this.

The only place where it provide an added value is that a photographer of given BT type has to use a Camera and all of a given type... but you could as well do it with only BT as parametrzed type:

```
public interface Photographer<BT extends BirdType> 
{
  BirdCamera<BT> getPhotographersCamera();
  BirdCall<BT> getPhotographersBirdCall();
  void examineCamera(BirdCamera<BT> camera);
}
```

And you get method would directly get a BirdType:

```
public <BT extends BirdType> Photographer<BT> get(BT birdType) {
[...]
}
```